# Estimating average of a random variable with lower variance is faster to converge than a variable with higher variance?

Tags: moving-average, exponential-smoothing

I have a fallowing problem:

I have to estimate average of 2 random variables $X$ and $Y$ based on average of two other. Where the $X$ and $Y$ are some $n$ by $n$ matrices.
$$
X = 0.5\cdot(A+B)
$$
$$
Y = 0.5\cdot(C+D)
$$

If I'm not wrong I can do it either way:

1. Estimate averages of variables $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ exponential moving average as $E[A], E[B], E[C], E[D]$.
2. Then estimate variables $X$ and $Y$ as $E[X] = 0.5\cdot(E[A]+E[B])$, and $E[Y] = 0.5\cdot(E[C]+E[D])$.

Or I have an option to do this another way, which seems to work better, because the variance of the estimated variables $X$ and $Y$ seems to be lower.

1. $X = 0.5\cdot(A+B)$, and $Y = 0.5\cdot(C+D)$.
2. Then estimate average of variables $X$ and $Y$ as $E[X] = 0.5\cdot(E[A]+E[B])$, and $E[Y] = 0.5\cdot(E[A]+E[B])$ using exponential moving average.

Nevertheless, I don't know which would be theoretically more valid and converge faster, when exponential moving average is used

Comment: How is exponential smoothing related to estimating averages?

Comment: @RichardHardy
If you've a time series, that is going forward and you don't have in advance all the incoming data, then with EWMA you can estimate the average.

Comment: Explaining how you use exponential smoothing could make your problem more transparent. Currently it is quite obscure in that regard.